# Is this correct sentence "Where have you been yesterday"?

Tags: american-english

I have got a question about Which of the following is correct sentence?

> Where have you been yesterday? 
>  
>   Where did you be yesterday?

If you can please let me know if there are something wrong, which one is wrong and how to fix them?

Comment: *Do* can’t be used as an auxiliary of *be*.

Comment: Anyway, we do not use present perfect with finish time.

Comment: The second sentence is only correct in some very specific dialects of English. It is generally considered _wrong_. The first sentence _could_ be correct if you mean "what places have you visited yesterday?", but _not_ if you mean _where were you yesterday?_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct phrasing is, "Where were you yesterday?"

"Have been" is continuous, so it doesn't make sense to use it with "yesterday", which is one specific time. You can say, "Where have you been the last few days?", but NOT "Where have you been yesterday?".

"Did be" is simply not used by native speakers. I don't know that it violates any general rule, but no one says that.

Comment: As for me, "yesterday" is a pretty big timespan from morning to evening, and not a single point in time :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Where have you been yesterday? (the word 'yesterday' relates to the past so it can not be used 'alone' in the present tense. By 'alone' i mean it can be used with the help of a preposition like 'since') So your question can be rephrased as
2. Where have you been since yesterday ?

   And your second question simply should be -
3. Where were you yesterday ?